# Searching for kind of tray to add HDDs to my computer case

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Zalman Desktop Case and I want to add a new harddisk. In the case is a disk cage and I need some kind of tray or rails to attach the HDD in the cage. I searched a lot on the internet but can't find somthing useful. Anybody an idea what I need?

[image]

Comment: A second hand computer that you can tear down.  On a container/ recycling park perhaps? Else check with Zalman what kind of HDD sled fits.

Answer (score 0):

For a desktop you're not going to be moving frequently [if at all] anything that bridges the gap will do. Thick card, plastic, wood. Just rest the HD on it. Done. It's not really a structural component.